# How to call two different CustomCell on their two different respective Button's Click

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have made two Custom Cells, one with two Labels and other having a Label and a TextField. I have two different buttons in a different View, I want to call a View(TableView) with Custom Cell having two Label by clicking on Button1, but when i click on Button2 it should call an other View(TableView) having other CustomCell.

Help me.

Answer (score 0):

In Button actions setSelected=YES to that button add all delegate and data source methods of table view check condition which button is selected according to that selected button you can change every thing..